# CSS padding text inside td not working

Tags: css

I have this simple HTML:

```
<table class="code_editor">
    <tr><td>RUN</td></tr>
    <tr><td>#include &#60;stdio.h&#62;</td></tr>
    <tr><td>int main(){</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="1indent">char answer[256];</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="1indent">printf("%s","Hello World!\n");</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="1indent">printf("%s","You can read this:");</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="1indent">if( scanf("%s", &answer) == 1 )</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="2indent">goto About_Me;</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="1indent">return 0;</td></tr>
    <tr><td>}</td></tr>
</table>
```

and also this simple CSS:

```
.1indent{
    padding-left: 10px;
}
.2indent{
    padding-left: 20px;
}
```

However, why my padding didn't affect my `<td>`? Here is my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wyt06rzp/1/)
There must be a silly mistake here..

Comment: Try using the browser developer tools to debug the problem. You would see the rule is not applied to the elements and could deduce something is wrong with the syntax

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in CSS2 classes identifiers can't start with a digit `[0..9]` [unless you escape them](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/grammar.html#tokenizer-diffs) e.g. `.\1indent`

so you may use instead an attribute selector

```
[class="1indent"] {
    padding-left: 10px;
}
[class="2indent"]  {
    padding-left: 20px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cnoLrs1h/

---

or you could just place the identation value as a suffix

```
.indent1 {
    padding-left: 10px;
}
.indent2 {
    padding-left: 20px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/s7exbr0r/

Comment: @user26409021 If the answer has solved your issue, you can accept it by pressing the checkmark next to it.

Comment: it's not weird, it's just css grammar